# How to send email attachments on android but prevent user from uploading attachments

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am using the Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE to be able to send email with attachments. The email is sent successfully with the attachment but it also allows user to upload attachments to some webservice.

What should I set in my intent to be able to send attachments but not show google drive kind of apps during intent handling.

Comment: One does not send attachments. You want to do something with some files. If the user chooses an email program the files can be send as attachments to the mail. If the user chooses a google drive kind of app then one speaks of files. Not of attachments.

Comment: The question is asking something different. I want to know how to send an email intent with attachments but not have any file uploading kind of apps like google drive show up. I only want to the email apps to show up.

Comment: I think you use a SHARE intent. Isnt it? Show complete code please.